# parts of the images in rectangle shape

Tags: java, image

We are trying to get only the portion of the image out of the captured image. But in java we only get subimage in rectangular form using image.getImage(x,y,width, height). Let say if i virutally split the image as 10 parts as shown below. How can i able to extract only 1,2,4,6,8,9,10 out of it as show in the second image using native java very without consuming too many resources and time.

[image]

[image]

### Update

Below is the sample code

```
for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        imagePart = img.getSubimage(x * this.smallWidth, y
                            * this.smallHeight, this.smallWidth,
                            this.smallHeight);

                        if (!ifSelectedPart(imagePart)) {
                            smallImages[x][y] = imagePart;


                        }
                    else {
                        smallImages[x][y] = fillwithAlpha();

                    }

   }

createImage(smallImages[][])
```

Comment: Show us some code that you have.

Answer (score 0):

If these rectangles are all the same size you can treat the image as a grid and calculate what region of the image you need with a little math.

```
int numberColumns = 2;
int numberRows = 5;

public Rectangle getSubregion(int row, int column, int imgWidth, int imgHeight){
    int cellWidth = imgWidth / numberColumns;
    int cellHeight = imgHeight / numberRows;
    return new Rectangle(column*cellWidth, row*cellHeight,cellWidth, cellHeight);
}

//usage
Rectangle cellOne = getSubregion(0, 0, img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());
```

Then just render each of those subregions to a new image in memory.

Comment: Is that will only get shape in rectangular form but not the shape i need.

Comment: If you need non-rectangular regions of your image, calculate the bounding rectangle of the non-rectangular region, then set the non-rect region as a clip, and render the bounding rectangle with that clip in place.  Let me know if you need clarification on that, its definitely the way you want to go.

Comment: I like that idea. Is that includes creating image using graphic2d? Can you rewrite your function?

Answer (score 0):

Images are by their nature rectangular. Perhaps you wish to draw over the image with 0 alpha composite color to cover up the region that you don't want to see. Either that or create a grid of rectangular sub-images, and keep the ones from the grid that you want to display.

Comment: Can you show programmatically? Especially how to fill with alpha

Comment: @user1595858: If you post your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first, I'll try to modify it.

Comment: Just updated with sample program. I need code for fillwithAlpha();

Comment: @user1595858: You've posted a code snippet, not a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's no way that I can compile, run or test a snippet. Please have a look at the link provided here and in my previous comment, and if you still need help, consider giving it a go. Yes, it will require effort on your part, but this is your question, so that's only fair.

Comment: I just need the function to modify the pixel to alpha although I can update the minimal example but it takes a while

Comment: @user1595858: I've got all the time in the world. Please let me know if you make any changes.